# In Github, is there a way to search for pull requests created by any author from a provided list?

Tags: github

For my team's weekly builds, I go through all pull requests from the company GitHub and pull out the PRs associated to my team. This requires an annoying sieving step that requires a walk-through of the company's previous week of code contribution.

I looked at the official GitHub search documentation ([HERE](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/)) and found the "author" field could be used to narrow down the search in the way I want, but when I try this at https://github.com/pulls it only works on one author at a time.

Is there a way to search across a list of authors?

For a little extra context, my team operates across a large list of repos, all of which are under a blanket organization which houses all repos across the company.

Comment: Are you asking for a method through their API? If so, what target language? If you're asking about their website; that sounds like a question that isn't programmatic in nature.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, Do you have a recommendation for where this question should go then? I read the "github" tag fully before posting this question and it fit the description perfectly fine. Why does this tag exist if my question is rejected by the SO community? There is a tag called "github-api" which is a perfect fit for your criticism, but I am not using that tag.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: FWIW, I think that the GitHub web-site falls under "software tools commonly used by programmers" -slash- "tools used primarily for programming" (from https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the full search at https://github.com/search.

Then simply add extra `author: <name>` fields to your query. The searching engine will OR fields. For example:

[`is:pr author:username1 author:username2`](https://github.com/search?q=is%3Apr%20author%3Ausername1%20author%3Ausername2)

(Note that this only works on https://github.com/search. The search syntax on other pages, like https://github.com/pulls, is severely limited and does not support searching by multiple authors. If you try the same search on https://github.com/pulls, GitHub will simply ignore all but one author that you list.)

To limit it to repositories by a specific owner, add the `user: <owner>` field to the query.

Answer (score 11):

Using the route github.com/search instead of github.com/pulls is the "right" answer in some sense, but I like the format of the /pulls page better. When working in a small team my approach is to use /pulls but substitute "involves" for "author", [like this](https://github.com/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+user%3AGitHub+involves%3Asmola+involves%3Amuan) (for reference, [the same query](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Apr%20user%3AGitHub%20author%3Asmola%20author%3Amuan) using /search and "author").

You will get "extra" hits where the author is someone outside the list, but it's another trick to know. (Names in the examples picked at random from recent public PRs)

Comment: There is no `involves' filter on projects, at least in the current version of projects (maybe it worked on classic ones)

Answer (score 3):

#### Option 1: Using Github's Search Query Language

- Go to https://github.com/search
- Type in a query following the format of this example (replacing `author:*` with your usernames.

  - Example: [`is:pr repo:zino-hofmann/graphql-flutter author:apackin author:kvenn`](https://github.com/search?q=is%3Apr+repo%3Azino-hofmann%2Fgraphql-flutter+author%3Aapackin+author%3Akvenn&type=Issues)

Explained

- `is:pr` - only PRs (since Github treats Issues and PRs both as "Issues")
- `repo:` - only show PRs in that repo
- `author:` - only show PRs for these authors

It shows as "Issues", but the list will only include PRs.
[image: Example]

#### Option 2: Fancy Bookmark/Alfred/Spotlight Search

You can modify the query params in the following URL to have the list of people on your team.

- Replacing `<username1,2,3,4>` with your teammates Github username's.
- Replacing <your_company> with your company URL (or removing that entirely if not on enterprise).

`https://github.<your_company>.com/search?q=author%3A<username1>+author%3A<username2>+author%3A<username3>+author%3A<username4>+is%3Apr&type=Issues`

#### Option 3: Using Github's Advanced Search UI

You can use Github's "Advanced Search" to achieve what you're looking for without needing to learn Github's query language.

- For public repos: [`http://github.com/search/advanced`](http://github.com/search/advanced)
- For internal/enterprise repos: `http://github.<your_company>.com/search/advanced`

You can use the fields below for filtering:

- To filter for specific repos, use "Advanced options" -> "In these repositories"
- To filter for specific authors, use "Issues options" -> "Opened by the author"

It uses query params under the hood, so you can generate the search with your UI and copy and paste it (to use for Option 3).

**Note**: You'll need to add "is:pr" to the resulting search query, no way to do that in the UI.

Comment: The question is for Pull Requests, not Issues. What you describe does not work for Pull Requests. Did you test it? It does not work.

Comment: This doesnot work with Pull requests, the question is specifically asking for PRs

Comment: @PeteH32, have you tried it? When I do it, it shows me PRs. I believe Github groups PRs and Issues together as "Issues" in the advanced search UI. I've been using the above to filter for PRs from my entire team for a while now.

Comment: If you want it to just show PRs, you can append `is:pr`. And in the URL it'll be `+is%3Apr`. But they'll still show up as "issues".

Comment: This answer is correct and, in my experience, the most thorough and reliable way to find PRs from multiple authors on a repo (especially on Github Enterprise instances where there seems to be a bug in other search methods which I've reported to Github). As Kyle points out, even though the GUI says "Issues" multiple places, it also includes PRs in the results.

Comment: Just to clarify, for "Option 3: Using Github's Advanced Search UI" you append `is:pr` in the "Advanced Search" text field at the top of the page. It's the same text field that automatically populates based on all the other criteria you add on the rest of the page. Or you can add it to the URL after you enter all your criteria and hit "search."

Answer (score 3):

#### Use the advanced search

Go to this page: https://github.com/search/advanced

Apply the filters like below:

[image]

In the results page, use the side panel filter for **Pull Requests**.

[image]

Comment: That gives you issues, not PR's

Comment: When using advanced search filters in GitHub, you might notice that the "Issues options" apply to both issues and pull requests. This is because they share some common attributes and metadata. In the results page, then, you can use the side panel on the left to specifically filter for pull requests. (I'll update the answer)

Answer (score 1):

With [GitHub CLI `gh` 2.28.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.28.0) (Apr. 2023) [`gh search prs`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_search_prs) would fit the bill:

The `--owner` flag can now take multiple values as well as CSV values.

```
gh search prs --owner user1 --owner user2 --owner user3,user4
```

That would show all PRs (Pull Requests) by user1, user2, user3 and user4.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very similar problem that I have encountered before.  To solve this problem I captured webhooks from GitHub into a database.  I know this is a "larger" solution than directly querying GitHub, but I think it is more maintainable.

If you are interested I wrote up the whole process [here](https://medium.com/@tim_visivo/quickly-create-a-github-dashboard-using-visivo-10371f1dfea1). In this article, I use Visivo (which I helped write) to accomplish the dashboarding.  It is a developer-friendly open-source CLI for creating charts.  Your change would require a trivial addition to the query of an `IN (names)` to the base query.

If you are interested, and there are additional charts you would find valuable as part of the GitHub dashboard, you can open up an issue on the dashboard repo [here](https://github.com/visivo-io/github-dashboard).

A big benefit of capturing the data is that you can write additional queries very quickly.